# Constrained optimization problem exam question

Tags: optimization, non-convex-optimization, qclp

> Consider the following constrained optimization problem:
>
> $$\min_{x} f = x_1 \\ \text{such that} \quad g_1=x_1^2+x_2^2-9 \leq0 \\ \qquad \qquad \ \ \quad \ g_2=-x_1^2-x_2^2+4 \leq0 \\ \qquad \ \ \ \ \  g_3 = x_1-x_2 \leq0$$
>
> How many stationary points and minimizers are there?

The sketch below shows the feasible domain in green. The monotonicity analysis shows that $g_2$ (the inner circle) is an active constraint.
[image]

For the stationary points we determine the gradient of $f$ and set it equal to $0$. Which is $\nabla f = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = 0$ Which does not yield an $x_1$ or $x_2$ value.

So I dont know how many stationary points and minimizers there are.

Comment: No, for stationary points we DO NOT determine the gradient of $f$ but the gradient of the Lagrangian function. You must take into account the constraints.

Comment: so i would have to use this formula: $\nabla f + \mu^{\top} \nabla g $?

Comment: Yes! Exactly :)

Comment: Thank you. A follow up question if I may. The monotonicity analyis shows that only $g_2$ is active. Then $\nabla f$ becomes $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\mu^{\top} \nabla g$ becomes $\begin{bmatrix} \mu_1 & \mu_2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} -2x_1 \\ -2x_2 \end{bmatrix}$ Is this correct?

Comment: Let $L = f+\mu^{T}g$. Then $$\partial_{x1}(L) = 1+2x_1\mu_1-2x_1\mu_2+\mu_3=0$$ and $$\partial_{x2}(L) = 2x_2\mu_1-2x_2\mu_2-\mu_3=0$$

Comment: Actually, by looking at your figure, it is clear that the minimum occurs when $(x_1,x_2) = (-3,0)$.

Comment: Thanks for all the help Alex.